# VS 2010 setting non-GUI class file as Component

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have an annoyance that has been occurring for quite some time with Visual Studio 2010.  I have a class file that I have made which VS saves as type "Component" for no reason I can discern.  If I forget and try to open the file, it looks for a designer which doesn't exist.

I have looked on Google and found some similar issues for VS 2005, but the problems seemed to be related to deriving from GUI component classes (listbox, combobox, etc).  This class does not do that.

The file is *GpsUtilities.cs*.  It appears in the csproj file as follows, with `SubType` of `Component`.  No other references to the file exist, i.e. nothing claims it as `DependentUpon`.

```xml
<Compile Include="Utilities\GpsUtilities.cs">
  <SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Even if I remove the `SubType` tag, and even if I explicitly set it to `Code` instead of `Component`, it still saves it as `SubType` of `Component`.

Here is the class structure (all the code stripped out).  As I said, it does not inherit, or even import the namespace of, anything GUI-related.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Timers;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AppNamespace
{
    public class GpsUtil : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public GpsUtil() { }

        public static GpsUtil CreateInstance() { }

        public bool IsGpsReady { get; }

        public GPSPort GpsSerialPort { get; private set; }

        public Timer GpsTimer { get; set; }

        private CircularArray<GpsPositionData> PositionBuffer { get; set; }

        private GpsPositionData m_GpsCurLoc;

        public GpsPositionData MyLocation { }

        public string GpggaPattern { get; set; }

        public Regex GpggaRegEx { get; set; }

        public GpsPositionData GpsPosDataFromRegExMatch(Match gpsRegExMatch) { }

        public void SetGpsPosition(double latitude, double longitude) { }

        private void gpsTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) { }

        private bool InitializeGpsPort() { }

        public bool TestGpsPort() { }

        public double ComputeSquaredDistance(double startLat, double startLon, double endLat, double endLon) { }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class GPSPort : SerialPort
    {
        public GPSPort(string portName, int baudRate = 9600) : base(portName, baudRate)
        {
        }

        private bool TestResult { get; set; }

        public bool Test(int interval = 3000, bool leavePortOpen = false) {}
    }

    public enum GpsFixQuality { Invalid = 0, GpsFix = 1, DgpsFix = 2 }

    [Serializable]
    public class GpsPositionData
    {
        public GpsPositionData() { }

        public GpsPositionData(double latitude, double longitude) {}

        public override string ToString() {}

        public bool IsCloseTo(GpsPositionData otherPoint, double tolerance = 0.0001) {}

        public GpsPositionData(DateTime time, double latitude, double longitude, GpsFixQuality fixQuality, int numberOfSatellites, double hdop, double altitude, double geodialSeparation, int ageOfDgps, string dgpsRefStationId){}

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime Time { get; private set; }

        [XmlElement("Latitude", typeof(double))]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Longitude", typeof(double))]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public GpsFixQuality FixQuality { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int NumberOfSatellites { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public double Hdop { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public double Altitude { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public double GeodialSeparation { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int AgeOfDgps { get; private set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string DgpsRefStationId { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not directly answer your question, but you can make VS open the code by default for everything. Rightclick the file, open with, select "source code editor" (not with encoding!), and click "Set as default" before you close the dialog.

Comment: I actually did something similar to that for opening XAML files as only XML.  I wanted something a little cleaner for this, so what Kent said below was best, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to keep all the classes in one file, you can use the `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]` attribute on the `GPSPort` class to override the default behavior.  [Details](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/06/10/codeviewinvs) here, note that you *must* use the fully qualified attribute even if you have a `using System.ComponentModel` statement or VS will ignore it.

Comment: Much better solution!  Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

At a guess, I'd say it's due to your `GPSPort` class, which extends `SerialPort`, which extends `Component`. Try removing that (or moving it into a separate file) and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: That did indeed fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem where `<SubType>Component</SubType>` keeps getting added and removed from the .csproj file - it seems that having additional types in the same file as for a type which derives from `System.ComponentModel.Component` was the cause. I split the types into separate files (as nature intended, and as you suggested) and it seems happier now.

Comment: wasn't 100% the same but this helped to solve my issue so -Up marked. Thanks