# Visual Studio opens my class-file (.cs) in the designer mode

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, ado.net

I've created a class that extends [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) in a brand new project.

```
public class FakeDbConnection : DbConnection { ... }
```

In the Solution Explorer the class looks like this: [image]

And when double-clicking it wants to open it in design mode which won't work. Opening up the .csproj-file reveals the problem

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="FakeADO\FakeDbConnection.cs">
    <SubType>Component</SubType>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Even if I remove the `SubType` tag VS2010 immediately re-adds it. Very annoying.

How can I stop VS2010 from opening up my .cs file in designer mode and just open it up as a regular code file?

Comment: Remove the file and add again and remember to change the type this time

Comment: Tried it and VS2010 re-adds the type as soon as I open the project.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As described in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256327/vs-2010-setting-non-gui-class-file-as-component) you can do this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
class FakeDbConnection: DbConnection { ... }
```

**Important:** The attribute needs to be [fully qualified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) otherwise VS2010 will ignore this.

**Important** (thanks to jmbpiano): The attribute only applies to the first class in the file.

Comment: Interesting...it does not work for me :-( I am using VS2010 and tried with a class that just inherits Component, and also tried with a class that inherits TabControl...no such luck...maybe it does not work on Express editions, although I find this highly unlikely!

Comment: Hmm, weird. Did you manually remove the <SubType> child-tag of the <Compile> tag in the .csproj-file?

Comment: Found the problem, you need to *fully* qualify the attribute, or it will not work.

Comment: +1 for finding the right answer instead of saying, "just live with it"

Comment: Anyone know if this has changed recently?  I'm using VS Pro 2013 and targeting .NET 3.5.  I made a class derived from WebClient (which, down the chain, derives from Component) and I have this same thing happening, but slapping this attribute on there (yes, fully qualified) does nothing.

Comment: I can confirm this works on VS Express 2013 for Desktop targeting both 3.5 and 4.5. I ran tests on classes derived from both Component and WebClient and everything worked as desired. I doubt Pro would work any differently.

Comment: There is one additional requirement to making this work that's worth mentioning: The DesignerCategory attribute need to be applied to the _first_ class in the file. If you've got multiple classes in the same code file, the IDE will ignore any DesignerCategory attributes applied to later classes.

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance hierarchy indicates that this class (`DbConnection`) inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. Try right click the file and View Source instead.

As always you can check MSDN! [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) is the documentation for `DbConnection`.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew this, but it's very cumbersome. Opening a file shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: @vidstige It's not exactly complicated, just not as easy as double clicking. Have a look in the Visual Studio settings and options. You might be able to find an option like "Open Component derivatives in source view by default". I know what you mean though, its annoying that components open in the designer when not all components are necessarily designable.

Comment: He who searches will find - See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because DBConnection inherits "Component".
About disabling VS to add "Subtype" in csproj-file - I don't think thats possible.

You can still aceess the code, by right-clicking in designer -> show code (I think "F7" is the shortcut key for that)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for the answer. I already knew that, but didn't put it in the question. Seems cumbers some. But if it's the only way I guess its a sort of work-around.